# mongodb how to get max three value from collections

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb collection like:

```
[{
    "name": "a",
    "price": 130
},
{
    "name": "b",
    "price": 90
},
{
    "name": "c",
    "price": 150
},
{
    "name": "e",
    "price": 170
},
{
    "name": "g",
    "price": 135
}]
```

I need a query to get max three "price" from this collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.find().sort({price:-1}).limit(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Query

- the answer with the sort and limit 3, is the simplest
- if many products can have the same price, maybe the 3 top prices is shared by more than 3 products, if you want all those products you can use this also, see the example, 135 price is shared from 2 products.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=626d6a107bf7deec3f506b00)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$setWindowFields": 
   {"output": {"rank": {"$denseRank": {}}}, "sortBy": {"price": -1}}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$lt": ["$rank", 4]}}}, {"$unset": ["rank"]}])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [.sort()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and [.limit()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) for that

sort in ascending order and then use limit

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({ price: -1 }).limit(3);
```